# Edit content button disabled in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

When I try to edit a CDE Dashboard, the only buttons enabled in toolbar are Open and New, but Save, Save As and, especially, Edit Content buttons are disabled.

I have tried to change profiles permissions (adding all to all users) and to put write permissions to authenticated users using the file properties too, with no effect. I have checked pentaho.xml and  tag seems to be correct:

```
        <operation>
            <id>EDIT</id>
            <perspective>wcdf.edit</perspective>
        </operation>
```

If I create a new CDE Dashboard, I'm able to save it using CDE toolbar, but I don't find the way to edit it later. Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

PD: Pentaho BI version: 5.4

Comment: Same problem... did you get a solution?